# Peterson's solution for process scheduling

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, mutual-exclusion

I'm trying to understand the Peterson's solution for mutual-exclusion problem so I'm sure that it works when process scheduling is preemptive but what happens when the scheduling is nonpreemptive? I read that it might crash when preemptive. So if I have to choose between two answers:

***a) The solution works only for preemptive process scheduling 

b) The solution works for preemptive process scheduling and in some cases for nonpreemptive process scheduling***

I'm not sure which one is more precisely correct?